# confluent docker cp-kafka-connect 4.0.0 - HTTP500 timeout & COORDINATOR_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: docker, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm running my current infrastructure using confluent docker images with version 3.3.1 and everything is working fine. Now I'm trying to setup a sandbox environment with v4.0.0 but I'm experiencing issues.

I'm having issues running cp-kafka-connect (v4.0.0) into docker image provided by confluent.

Infrastructure details: I'm using docker image cp-kafka:4.0.0 as well as for zookeeper and all my streams/consumers/producers applications i have on the infrastructure are working just perfect. Just cp-kafka-connect:4.0.0 is not working.
kafka is running with auto topic creation active.

I've run connect container with these env variables:

```
-e CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka1.kafka:9092,kafka2.kafka:9092,kafka3.kafka:9092
-e CONNECT_GROUP_ID=connect-03
-e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect03-config
-e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect03-offsets
-e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect03-status
-e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
-e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
-e CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
-e CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
-e CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka-connect-03.kafka
-e CONNECT_REST_PORT=8083
-e CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL=TRACE
-e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE=false
-e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE=false
-e CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE=false
-e CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE=false
```

however when I perform the REST call:

```
curl -X GET http://kafka-connect-03.kafka/connectors/ -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/json'
```

i receive after a couple of minutes an HTTP 500 Timeout error.

tailing kafka-connect container I can see this (please note: this message is printed independently from the cUrl call and is printed forever):

```
    [2017-12-31 17:55:40,099] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect03] Sending GroupCoordinator request to broker kafka3.kafka:9092 (id: 1009 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2017-12-31 17:55:40,099] TRACE [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect03] Sending FIND_COORDINATOR {coordinator_key=connect03,coordinator_type=0} with correlation id 3098 to node 1009 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-12-31 17:55:40,100] TRACE [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect03] Completed receive from node 1009 for FIND_COORDINATOR with correlation id 3098, received {throttle_time_ms=0,error_code=15,error_message=null,coordinator={node_id=-1,host=,port=-1}} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-12-31 17:55:40,100] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect03] Received GroupCoordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1514742940100, latencyMs=1, disconnected=false, requestHeader=RequestHeader(apiKey=FIND_COORDINATOR, apiVersion=1, clientId=consumer-1, correlationId=3098), responseBody=FindCoordinatorResponse(throttleTimeMs=0, errorMessage='null', error=COORDINATOR_NOT_AVAILABLE, node=:-1 (id: -1 rack: null))) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2017-12-31 17:55:40,100] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect03] Group coordinator lookup failed: The coordinator is not available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2017-12-31 17:55:40,100] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect03] Coordinator discovery failed, refreshing metadata (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
```

meanwhile on kafka logs I can see no errors.

I've tried:

- to leave connect/kafka to create the topics (config, offsets and status)

RESULT: only offsets topic is created

- to create the topics by myself before

RESULT: nothing worth of notice

- with every new attempt I've changed groupId / appId config/offsets/status topics names (in order to avoid any issue of dirty setup)

Any clue of this behaviour?

Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: A couple of things to check: first check further up in the container logs. Right after the config is printed you may get more info. Second, try the connector-plugins endpoint just to see if anything comes back for available plugins. Not saying it'll fix it, just thinking about where I'd troubleshoot first

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I realized where the problem was.
I was starting up kafka container without KAFKA_BROKER_ID env variable. This brings up a kefka broker with a pseudo-random number (eg 1007).

Happened that some cluster config messed up since I started/stopped kafka containers several times. In fact, inspecting the cluster, I saw that the cluster was composed of 3 broker (alive, 1007,1008,1009) and other 3 were offline (1004,1005,1006).
When I created cp-kafka-connect the first time was with the first 3 brokers, than something got corrupted.

Now I cleaned up everything, I placed KAFKA_BROKER_ID in each kafka broker and everything works.

Thanks a lot.